# How to use updatable views in entity framework using code first

Tags: entity-framework

We're using entity framework code first for DB tables. Now the data base has been moved to another  dev server and the DBA has created updatable view to work with instead of tables. I changed the connection string and it started giving error "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database............"
Looked like since the table is not there is the DB, EF is trying to create one. I followed the steps at

[entity-framework-code-first-and-pre-generated-views](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/05/28/entity-framework-code-first-and-pre-generated-views/)

[how-to-work-with-updatable-views](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx)

Basically created the edmx file and manually remove DefininingQuery tags and change store:views to tables and generate view and add to the project. But I am still getting the same error.

I am new to EF and not clearly understand what I am doing here. Basically I need to tell EF from here on wards use this database and instead of the tables used earlier, use these updatable views. I am not sure database migration is needed here. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Manage to solve it by creating a New DatabaseIntializer that does nothing and tell DbContext to use this Databaseinitlizer isntead of default. Here is code:

```
internal class DatabaseInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<DB>
{

  public void InitializeDatabase(DB context) {}      

}

public class DB : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DB() : base("name=ClientMgmtConnection") 
    {            
       System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());
    }
}
```